CRRA and CARA utility
I frequently see CRRA and CARA utility functions, and I was wondering what's the history of thoughts behind this ? I mean, I guess (although not sure) that it is linked to discrete/continuous time so that for large $t$ we get  $e^x = 1+x$. But if anyone could like explain, with simple words and a bit of maths what's the idea behind this, what triggered the use of one instead of the other, etc...
